# UWP Style in a nested ItemsController not working

Tags: c#, user-controls, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I have a User Control that works in the sense that it displays the data that it needs to display, the issue I have is the the style doesn't appear to be working in the most inner ItemsControl.

The style is working on the outer ItemsControl, which kind of has me stumped.

App.Xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Dictionaries/StyleDictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

UserControl.xaml

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind Cat.Content}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Style="{StaticResource myStyleTextBlock_Header}" />
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Body}">
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource myStyleTextBlock_Paragraph}" Text="{Binding Body}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I was reading something about styles being encapsulated within User Controls, but if the outer style in the template works why does the second one not get applied.

Edit:

Maybe I should try to explain what I am trying to do and someone can suggest a better way.

Right now I have a class that has something like this.

```
public class Content
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public List<string> Body { get; set; }
}
```

And the user control is them just

```
<UIControls:DisplayDossierText />
```

The style is very simple, it is just styling a textbox to have colors and margins etc.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="myStyleTextBlock_PageHeader">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,25,15" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#007bb8" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="myStyleTextBlock_Paragraph" BasedOn="{StaticResource myStyleTextBlock_Header}">
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,15,30" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ff00063e" />
</Style>
```

So the idea is that the control displays the header, the the collection of body in the style. As state above, the header is styled fine, but the body text has no style applied to it at all.

I have been trying to find a good solution to this, best way to approach it and found nothing. So playing around I cam up with what I have at the  moment, but I feel that this is probably not the best solution to what I am trying to achieve.

There is currently no Code Back for this, but the normal shell of code created when creating the control.

Anyway, I am getting the suspicion that I need to be going in a different direction and not really sure how to go about this. All examples I find are based on styling a control with the basics of a button or listview. While listview is kind of what this is, it will not be interactive. It's main purpose is to provide an easy way to change paragraphs of text and store it in a database and then pull it up and display it.

Anyone?

Comment: I can't find `ParagraphText_FontSizeWide` StaticResource . Could you provide full of you `StaticResource` referenced by `TextBlock` style?

Comment: I have edited it to hard code the values.